# zero item added at the end while creating numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

As you can see from the following ipdb log, extra zero dates are added to *pre* and *post* arrays.
How can i fix this? And why this happens?

```
ipdb> pre
(datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 9, 58), 0, 1)

ipdb> post
(datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 13, 15), 0, 1)

ipdb> RDT
RDT = [(COL_TIME, 'M8[s]'), (COL_STATUS, 'b'), (COL_MOBILE, 'b')]

ipdb> RMATCH
RMATCH = [(COL_PRE, RDT), (COL_POST, RDT)]

ipdb> ppre, ppost = np.array(pre, dtype=RDT), np.array(post, dtype=RDT)

ipdb> ppre
array((datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 9, 58), 0, 1), 
      dtype=[('TIME', '<M8[s]'), ('STATUS', 'i1'), ('MOBILE', 'i1')])

ipdb> np.array([ppre, ppost], dtype=RMATCH)
array([ ((datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 9, 58), 0, 1), (datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0, 0)),
       ((datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 13, 15), 0, 1), (datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0, 0))], 
      dtype=[('PRE', [('TIME', '<M8[s]'), ('STATUS', 'i1'), ('MOBILE', 'i1')]), ('POST', [('TIME', '<M8[s]'), ('STATUS', 'i1'), ('MOBILE', 'i1')])])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last result is an array with dtype `RMATCH` containing two elements.  `ppre` and `ppost` were each converted to this dtype.

If you expected an array with a single element, with `ppre` filling the first field of the `RMATCH` dtype and `ppost` filling the second, try this:

```
np.array([(ppre, ppost)], dtype=RMATCH)
```

(Note the extra parentheses.)

I'm not sure if it is a bug, a wart or a feature that `np.array([ppre, ppost], dtype=RMATCH)` didn't raise an error, and instead filled in the unused fields with 0.